# css centering is affecting widget

Tags: html, css

For some reason my css centering code is messing with a widget. The widget is being pushed down below the columns. Also, the nav bar widget is on all pages of the forum.

I'd really, really appreciate any help at all. Thanks.

Picture of problem: http://i1335.photobucket.com/albums/w662/dnpranks/Untitled15_zps89a1c5e9.png

~Widget is suppose to be up more, right next to the columns.

Below is the code to the columns that's causing the problem:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Pricies Table</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_price_table_dark.css" />
</head>

<body>
   <div class="left">
        <div class="pricing_table_row">
        <div class="first_child">
            <div class="title_first_colum"><center><img src="http://i1335.photobucket.com/albums/w662/dnpranks/_slotbutton__zpsb8778ee4.png"></center></div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4IOlEBU.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum black"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/FrohEbX.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GnnOkkw.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pvJPDni.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/xux1rsZ.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Krg86nA.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/6yBmM4e.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4D1nzMY.png"></li>
            <li class="first_colum"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZFtOSeS.png"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ptable">
    <div class="pricing_table_row">
        <div class="first_child">
            <div class="title">Bet</div>
            <div class="price">100<br /><span class="small">DP</span></div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>600</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>400</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>300</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>200</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>200</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>100</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>-50</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>-100</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletter"><strong><br>-200</br></strong></center></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pricing_table_row">
        <div class="first_child">
            <div class="title">Bet</div>
            <div class="pricet">75<br /><span class="small">DP</span></div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>400</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>300</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>200</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>150</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>150</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>75</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>-50</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>-75</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><div class="colorlettert"><center><strong><br>-150</br></strong></center></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>

    <div class="pricing_table_row">
        <div class="first_child">
            <div class="title">Bet</div>
            <div class="pricew">50<br /><span class="small">DP</span></div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>300</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>200</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>150</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>100</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>100</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>50</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>-25</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>-50</br></strong></center></li>
            <li><center><div class="colorletterw"><strong><br>-75</br></strong></center></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>  

  <div class="left">
  <form method="post" action="/posting.forum" onsubmit="return vB_Editor['text_editor'].prepare_submit(0, 0)" name="post" id="quick_reply">

   <div style="clear: both; margin-left: auto; width: 150px; margin-right: auto; height: 169px;" id="textarea_content">
       <textarea editorid="text_editor" cols="50" rows="10" name="message" style="font-size: 1.0m;" id="text_editor_textarea" class="inputbox">Bet Amount: </textarea> 
   </div>

    <center>
       <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="reply" /><input type="hidden" name="sid" value="26766" /><input type="hidden" name="t" value="3671" /><br /><input onclick="confirm('Make sure that the requested item(s) is(are) in the Supreme Market list and that you have sufficient amount Duel Points for it.');" type="submit" class="button1" value="Send" name="post" /> 
    </center>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
/*
DICE GAME TABLE
*/

/* Elements styles */
.pricing_table_row {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:245px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#444444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.left {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:1024px;
min-width:auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
        margin-left: -28%;
}
.pricing_table_row ul {
    list-style:none
    width:232px;
    margin:3;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#444444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}
.pricing_table_row ul {
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    width:232px;
    margin:0;
    padding:3px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#444444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.pricing_table_row ul li {
    border:1px solid #5b5b5b;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    margin-top:6px;
  width: 232px;
    height: 101px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.pricing_table_row ul li {
    font-size:50px;
    height: 101px;
}
.first_child{
    margin-top:6px; 
    border: 2px solid #5b5b5b;
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height: 159px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align:center;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 4px;
}

.last_child{
    float:left;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-left: 3px; 
    border: 1px solid #5b5b5b;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    height: 120px;
    width: 232px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    text-align:center;
}

.title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 41px;
    width: 212px;
    margin: 10px 9px 9px 9px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #91040b;
}
.title_first_colum{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #01b8e2;
    height: 159px;
    width: 232px;
    margin:0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.price{
    padding-top: 13px;
    color: #6e8c92;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 75px;
    width: 212px;
    margin: 9px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 34px;
}
.pricet{
  padding-top: 13px;
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 75px;
    width: 212px;
    margin: 9px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 34px;
}
.pricew{
  padding-top: 13px;
  color: #ff6600;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 75px;
    width: 212px;
    margin: 9px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 34px;
}
.colorletter{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 50px;
    color: #6e8c92;
}
.colorlettert{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ff0000;
}
.colorletterw{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #ff6600;
}


.price_small{
    color: #01b8e2;
    padding-top: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 67px;
    width: 232px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.subprice{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.subprice_small{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.small{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.list_check {
    background:url(../images/icon_check_dark.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    }
.list_x {
    background:url(../images/icon_x_dark.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    }
.button{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 232px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #01b8e2;
}
.button:hover{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 232px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.first_colum{
  text-align: left;
    padding-left: 0px; 
}
.black{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing this `clear:both` near the end of your HTML code, and see if that fixes the problem. Without seeing the code live I can't tell for sure if it'll fix it, but I've had very similar problems myself with `clear` pushing down other content.

Change:

```
   <div style="clear: both; margin-left: auto; width: 150px; margin-right: auto; height: 169px;" id="textarea_content">
       <textarea editorid="text_editor" cols="50" rows="10" name="message" style="font-size: 1.0m;" id="text_editor_textarea" class="inputbox">Bet Amount: </textarea> 
   </div>
```

To:

```
   <div style="margin-left: auto; width: 150px; margin-right: auto; height: 169px;" id="textarea_content">
       <textarea editorid="text_editor" cols="50" rows="10" name="message" style="font-size: 1.0m;" id="text_editor_textarea" class="inputbox">Bet Amount: </textarea> 
   </div>
```